# A theorem about cardinal numbers(an inequality)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> **Theorem.** Let $\{ A_k | k \in K \}$ be a collection of sets indexed by the $K$, with $|K| = \kappa$. If $\forall k \in K \ \ |A_k| \leq \lambda$, then
>
> $|\bigcup\limits_{k \in K} A_k| \leq \lambda\kappa$

I wonder how to prove the theorem. One way I can think of is to construct an injection

$f: \bigcup\limits_{k \in K} A_k \to M \times K$ where $|M| = \lambda$

knowing that $\forall k \in K$ we have an injection

$g_k: A_k \to M$

Any hints?

Comment: This looks like it will depend someway or another on the axiom of choice, so maybe instead construct a surjection from $\lambda\kappa$ to $|\bigcup_{k\in K}A_k|$ (Hint: choose surjections $f_k:\lambda\to A_k$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re on the right track.

Since $|K|=\kappa$, you might as well replace $K$ by $\kappa$ and index the sets by ordinals less than $\kappa$. For each $\xi\in\kappa$ you have an injection $f_\xi:A_\xi\to\lambda$. Define

$$f:\bigcup_{\xi\in\kappa}A_\xi\to\kappa\times\lambda$$

as follows: for each $x\in\bigcup_{\xi\in\kappa}A_\xi$ let

$$\eta(x)=\min\{\xi\in\kappa:x\in A_\xi\}\;,$$

and let

$$f(x)=\langle\eta(x),f_{\eta(x)}(x)\rangle\;.$$

Now just verify that $f$ is a well-defined injection.

Comment: I view cardinal numbers as equivalence classes of "there is a bijection between two sets" relation. Honestly, I don't know about ordinals and now sure can we replace $K$ by $\kappa$, since $K$ is a set and $\kappa$ is a cardinal number.

Comment: @Jxt921: The [von Neumann definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) of ordinal numbers, which is by far the most common and easiest to use, makes them sets; specifically, each is the set of all smaller ordinals. In particular, $0=\varnothing$, $\omega=\Bbb N$, and $\alpha+1=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$ for any ordinal $\alpha$. The cardinal numbers are then simply initial ordinals, i.e., ordinals that are not the same cardinality as any smaller ordinal.

Comment: @Jxt921: You can mimic this argument without von Neumann ordinals by letting $\le$ be a well-order on $K$, and for each $x\in\bigcup_{k\in K}A_k$ letting $j(x)=\min_{\le}\{k\in K:x\in A_k\}$. For each $k\in K$ you have an injection $f_k:A_k\to M$, and you set $f(x)=\langle j(x),f_{j(x)}(x)\rangle\in K\times M$.

Comment: I see. So we use Axiom of Choice, that is, every set can be well ordered. However is $j: \bigcup\limits_{k \in K} A_k \to K$ injective? How can this be checked or/and proved?

Comment: Nevermind, I know it's not, and we doesn't need it. We only need to prove that $f$ is injective, where a proof doesn't rely on $j$'s injectivity hypothesis. $f(x_1)=f(x_2) \Rightarrow (j(x_1), f_{j(x_1)}(x_1)) = (j(x_2), f_{j(x_2)}(x_2)) \Rightarrow j(x_1) = j(x_2), f_{j(x_1)}(x_1) = f_{j(x_2)}(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1 = x_2$ since $f_k$ is injective. Thank you.

Comment: @Jxt921: Yep, you’ve got it. You’re welcome.